# Ничего не выводится на странице

Tags: php, mamp

Полностью почистил мак, и заново все установил. Скачал vscode и mamp. Запустил сервер, и добавил туда файл index.php  с кодом `<?php echo 'it works'; ?>`. Перехожу на http://localhost:8888 и страница пустая. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Может сервер другой порт слушает. попробуй http://localhost:8080

Comment: Нет, не в этом дело. Сервер работает, но на странице нет никакого текста

Comment: Я привык, что все изменения кода сохраняются автоматически. После добавления записи, я не сохранил код, поэтому ничего не отображалось на странице